# Htaccess rewrite url gives 500 Internal server error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am getting 500 Error internal with following code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /get.php?action=$1 [L]
```

The rewrite module is Active , Safe mode is OFF and there is no problem,

I tested this code :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

But nothing changed.

What to do now ?

Comment: What does your log says?

Comment: @RahilWazir No log found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me the issue is that you're not setting any limits, so it loop's your redirect.

Here is an example that would stop since the file get.php exists.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /get.php?action=$1 [L]
```

To further explain, what happens in your example is that it redirects to `get.php` over and over and over, because your rule tells anything not a `/` to internally redirect but not to stop if a file exits, and since `get.php` also falls under your regex expression, it would redirect again.

What the 2 conditions I have added does is, it tells it to stop if a file or folder exists.

If you're using HTTPD version 2.4+ you could have simple used the flag [`[END]`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end), like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /get.php?action=$1 [END]
```

Which tells the server to stop any further redirects.

Comment: WOW, IT fixed :D Tnx alot.

Comment: +1 for the [`[END]`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end)

Comment: ofcorse , It has a time limit to be approved ;)

Comment: @Pafo yes :) it does unhappily